# Using Generics with POJO

Tags: java, generics, option-type

I wish to return multiple different POJO object responses from a method depending upon the input using generics. The POJOs are not part of a hierarchy i.e. are totally independent POJO

```
//POJO1
class A1  implements Serializable {

   // Instance variable with getter and setter

}

//POJO2
class B1 implements Serializable {

  // Instance variable with getter and setter

}


class XYZ {

   private ObjA objA;
   private ObjB objB;

   public <T>Optional<T>  getResponse(String input) {


       if(input.equals("A")) {       
           return objA.getResponse();  // This returns an optional of POJO A1 or Optional.empty()
       } else {
           return objB.getResponse();  // This returns an optional of POJO B1 or Optional.empty()
       }
   }
}
```

However I get the error `Incompatible types. Required Optional<T> but 'of' was inferred to Optional<T>: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that A1 conforms to T inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: T lower bounds: A1`

I tried attaching generic tags to POJO class definition, but to no avail. Can someone please point out where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I think you don't really need to do all of that. Would you consider making `input` a `Enum`?  If yes I'll  post an answer using Enum

Comment: Passing enum as input is not the point of question. Its about using generics to return different POJO objects

Comment: You need not let bad style oncommented when you see it. Also, if you change input.equals("A") to "A".equals(input) or Objects.equals(input, "A") you'll ultimately avoid NullPointerExceptions even without checking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to let a compile time type `T` depend on the run time value of `input`, which is not possible. Since the value is dynamic, you can not know which type will be returned, so the correct approach is to use `Optional<?>`:

```
public Optional<?>  getResponse(String input) {
   if(input.equals("A")) {       
       return objA.getResponse();  // This returns an optional of POJO A1 or Optional.empty()
   } else {
       return objB.getResponse();  // This returns an optional of POJO B1 or Optional.empty()
   }
}
```

If the value of `input` *is* statically known, you can create 2 methods with different return types:

```
public Optional<A1> getResponseA1() {
    return objA.getResponse();
}

public Optional<B1> getResponseB1() {
    return objB.getResponse();
}
```

And call one of those instead of passing the string, e.g.:

```
// Optional<?> result = xyz.getResponse("A"); // Not this
Optional<A1> result = xyz.getResponseA1(); // But this
```

Or you could use both approaches and let the caller decide which one to use based on if they know the value of the string or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast:

```
if(input.equals("A")) {       
    return (T) objA.getResponse();
} else {
    return (T) objB.getResponse();
}
```

Note that while this will resolve the compilation problem, it doesn't guarantee type safety as the expected as the target type can technically still be incompatible with the actuall object being returned.

It's also assumed that the caller should expect an `Optional<A1>` or `Optional<B1>`

Comment: This would only make sense, if T is assignable to both responses. But then you wouldn't need to cast.

Comment: You wouldn't need to cast the method's return value

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the type to be determined based on the input into the function?

```
public <T>Optional<T>  getResponse(String input) {
```

The return T of this function is always going to be what was specified in the calling method.

Instead consider something like this:

```
public Optional<Serializable> getResponse(String input) {
```

Then when using the function you can do something like this:

```
Optional<Serializable> s = getResponse("test");
s.ifPresent(sPresent -> {
    if(sPresent instanceof A1.class) {
        //logic for A1
    } else if(sPresent instanceof B1.class) {
        //logic for B1
    } else {
        //throw exception
    }
}
```